# [PHP]Parse Error

Tags: php

I am using this code:

```
<?php
$pid=$_GET["pid"];
$pname=$_GET["pname"];

$pnamecheck=array("test")

if ($pname == $pnamecheck[$pid]) {
echo "You are using a Licenced Version of Program."
}
else
{
echo "You are using a Crack Version of Program!"
}

?>
```

And Getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in ... on line 7
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **programming** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Programming questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Comment: See: [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing semicolons (;) at the end of your statements. See below fixed version:

```
$pnamecheck=array("test");

if ($pname == $pnamecheck[$pid]) {
echo "You are using a Licenced Version of Program.";
}
else
{
echo "You are using a Crack Version of Program!";
}
```